# How do I release a task that has been claimed?

Tags: java, bpmn, activiti

I'm using BPMN workflow to assign a task to an assignee.
How do I release (backward) the task so it will be available for previous candidate before it was assigned?

http://www.activiti.org/userguide/index.html#bpmnFirstExampleCode

Answer (score 2):

Setting the task assignee to `null` will do the job:

```
taskService.setAssignee(task.getId(), null);
```

See also this [forum post](http://forums.activiti.org/en/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=1743&start=0).